# Improving my application package regarding Maths undergraduate grades [for Master in Economics Program]

Tags: mathematics, application, economics

I am looking for some recommendations about how I could enhance my application package for a Master (MA/MSc) in Economics, considering that I have low grades in mathematics courses, despite that I took 4 courses in this realm.

I really like mathematics and I believe that I am good on it. For example, after I finished my undergraduate career in Economics, I applied some of the knowledge acquired from previous courses through econometric modelling.

For that reason, taking into consideration that I have plans for studying abroad, I would like to know if there are some courses, international/standarized exams or any other strategies (considering the other sides of the application) in order to improve my mathematics grades register and convince the committee for graduate admissions. For example, I am considering to take the GRE as soon as possible.

Thank you very much!
Greetings from Peru.